# CSS - aligning FontAwesome icons with an icon inside a text input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've set up a fiddle so you can see what's going on: https://jsfiddle.net/5p9ve8xr/1/

What I'm trying to do is make it so that the 3 social media icons (`.fa-linkedin`, `.fa-twitter`, `.fa-facebook`) horizontally align with the center of the search icon (`.fa-search`)

The social media icons all have a class of `.social`. So I've tried targetting them with padding and margins, e.g.

```
.social {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

But this just pushes all the elements down by 20px.

I've attached a screenshot to illustrate the point. I want the icons such that the amount of space occupied by the green and magenta is equal - i.e. the icons are exactly in the center of the search input:

[image]

Here's a copy of the code - in case it's not on jsfiddle at any point...

Markup:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid red">
                <form action="#" class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" size="30" placeholder="Search" class="form-control input-lg">
                        <i id="filtersubmit" class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i>


                         <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x social" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                         <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x social" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                         <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x social" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </form>
        </div>
     </div>
```

CSS:

```
#filtersubmit {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -42px;
    top: 5px;
    color: #7B7B7B;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 0;
}
```

Libraries:

- Bootstrap 3.3.7
- FontAwesome
- jquery 1.12.4

Comment: I've posted a fiddle with all the code I have?!

Comment: Calm down. I've copied the code on to here...

Comment: I'm perfectly calm, although a little drunk :), Thanks for that.

Comment: Have you tried adding `fa-fw` to the classes of each icon? http://fontawesome.io/examples/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably adjust your structure ever-so-slightly

```css
.form-search--social {
    float: right;
    padding: 8px 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid red">
  <form action="#" class="form-inline form-search">
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" size="30" placeholder="Search" class="form-control input-lg">
     <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i id="filtersubmit" class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i>
     </span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-search--social">
     <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x fa-fw social" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
     <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x fa-fw social" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
     <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x fa-fw social" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

And because it rendered weird in SOs code box; to avoid any potential confusion here is a Bootply of the end result: https://www.bootply.com/dmC7mKGr1L